# Why is background image not showing up for footer?

Tags: html, css, background-image

As seen in the image below, my background image for the `footerImage` div for my footer are not showing up, even though there is a clearly defined height (50px) and width (100%) for the div as shown by the green border. Why? How do I fix this?

*Note:* It's NOT an image path issue because I can pull up a preview of the image in Brackets.

**My footer:**
[image]

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="" target="_blank"> <figure>
            <div class = "footerImage resume"> </div>
            <figcaption>Resume</figcaption>
        </figure></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
.footerImage {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid green;
}

.footerImage .resume {
    background-image: url('../images/resume.png');
}
```

Comment: live demo : https://jsfiddle.net/fp4fye3a/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

edit this css for your div

```
.footerImage.resume {
    background-image: url('../images/resume.png');
}
```

since they are both classes of the same div their should be no gap between `.footerImage` and `.resume`

Answer (score 4):

The class that you have applied is written is wrong . You need to use `.footerImage.resume` instead of `.footerImage .resume` Please look at the sample code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        .footerImage {
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: contain;
            background-position: center center;
            width: 100%;
            height: 50px;
            border: 1px solid green;
        }
        
        .footerImage.resume {
            background-image: url('http://weknowyourdreams.com/images/bird/bird-06.jpg');
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="" target="_blank">
                <figure>
                    <div class="footerImage resume"> </div>
                    <figcaption>Resume</figcaption>
                </figure>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the space between .footerImage and .resume

```
.footerImage.resume {
    background-image: url('../images/resume.png');
}
```

or you can just use

```
.resume {
    background-image: url('../images/resume.png');
}
```